# How to observe third party event in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've a third party plugin, which throws an event which I can catch using: `plugin.onSuperAwesomeEvent(function () { /*do magic once event is fired */})`

Now my problem is, that this event can be fired more often and I need to be aware of this. How can I make it observable or subscribe-able?

Comment: "Throws an event" ?? Please provide more concrete information. What event? DOM event, observable, ... What "third party"?

Comment: Sorry. It is a script I embed. Once it is instantiated, I call `plugin.load();` and then I have to use `plugin.onPluginReady(function() { /*do magic once event is fired */  })`. My problem is, that this event can be fired more then once and I would like to be aware every time `plugin.onPluginReady()` is triggered.

Comment: The same code should work in Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an observable from almost anything. You can try this:

```
var pluginEventStream = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    plugin.onPluginReady(function(evt) { observer.next(evt) })
});

pluginEventStream.subscribe(function(evt) {
    // do magic
});
```